# Laravel how create a virtual model as "join" of two models

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I would create a virtual model modelC (with no real table on the DB) as join between model modelA and model modelB. My need is to access to model modelC like a standard model and access to his attributes  (modelA and modelB atributes) without accessit to them like

```
ModelC::find(1)->modelA->atribute_of_modelA
```

but accessing to them like

```
ModelC::find(1)->attribute_of_modelA.
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to me, your request is absolutely unnecessary. You already got access to ModelA and ModelB with all their data. If possible, can you pls update your question sharing the context why you need to do so?

If you still insist on doing so. You could create [a view](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_view.asp) in your db that joins ModelA and ModelB together, name it model_cs table. That could be wired to the modelC model.

Alternatively, and this is something I don't highly recommend, you can use [Laravel Sushi](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-sushi). So you can hydate your ModelC this way:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Sushi\Sushi;

class ModelC extends Model
{
    use Sushi;

    public function getRows()
    {
        return ModelA::join('model_b', ...)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it because I create the models at runtime, so I haven't the names and number of models' istances: for this reason I can't use Query->ModelName->Attributes and I need to access directly to Query->Attributes. Any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved overriding 2 methods of ModelB:

```
    public function newQuery()
    {
        $query = parent::newQuery();
        $query->join('ModelB_Table', 'ModelB_table.id_user', '=', 'ModelA_table.id');
        return $query;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        $this->fields = Schema::getColumnListing($this->table);
        if (isset($this->fields[$key])) {
            return $this->fields[$key];
        }
        return parent::__get($key);
    }
```

This works with ModelB that has an external key for ModelA, but it is easy to modify to use with ModelA, ModelB, and ModelC structure.

Might be this can help others.